# Java app or Groovy Script to store an image file as .jpg from http response body with content type as image/jpeg in SOAP UI

Tags: image, soapui, httpresponse

An API GET response returns an image in the body, like this: This is not an attachment.

```
Date : Fri, 05 May 2017 12:26:00 GMT
status : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length : 12888
Content-Type : image/jpeg
Server : Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff
Cache-Control : no-cache
Cache-Control : no-store
Cache-Control : max-age=0

ÿØÿà JFIF  ` `  ÿáÈExif  MM *    2       J;       ^GF       GI     ?  ‡i       
f   Æ2009:03:12 13:48:28 Corbis   ?       œ?       °’‘    17  ’’    17      
2008:02:11 11:32:43 2008:02:11 11:32:43                       (             $      

œ       `      `   ÿØÿÛ C       

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛ C         

2!!2 ...... and so on.
```

Postman decodes the image an displays it, it is an animal in this case.

I have to store the response as an image file (.jpg) using a groovy script in soapUI(soapUI is used to test the API)

This is what I've tried in a Groovy Script step, but the image saved is unintelligible malformed.

```
testRunner.runTestStepByName("GETjpg");
def getImageResponse = 
context.testCase.testSteps["GETjpg"].getPropertyValue("Response");
byte[] imageData = getImageResponse.getBytes();
// Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
String imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);

// Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array
byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(imageDataString);

// Write a image byte array into file system
FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\animal.jpg");
imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
imageOutFile.close();

public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(imageByteArray);
}

public static byte[] decodeImage(String imageDataString) {
    return new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(imageDataString);
}
```

I guess that what I am doing to save the image in .jpg is not correct. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did this. From the Script Assertion of the http GET request. Hope It helps someone.

```
def ins = context.httpResponse.getRawResponseBody();
def isImageSaved = false;
InputStream inputStream;
FileOutputStream outputStream;
if (ins){
    try {
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ins);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(context.expand("C:\\animal.jpg")));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        isImageSaved = true;

    }catch (Exception e){
        log.error e;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();       
    }   
} else {
    log.error "image does not exist...";
}

context.testCase.setPropertyValue("isImageSaved", isImageSaved.inspect());
```

Comment: Just arrived at the same thing - almost. I struggled with .getRawResponse(). Then I was trimming the headers part by searching for the JFIF stuff. Succeeded with a massive workaround. .getRawResponseBody() doesn't require that. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

You need to get the actual bytes (raw) to avoid transformations to text tempering with the byte arrays.

```
byte[] response = context.httpResponse.getRawResponseBody()

pathname = "C:\\Users\\mdirickx\\Pictures\\soapui\\file_cat_bytesRaw05.jpeg"
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pathname);
fos.write(response);
fos.close();
```

## The Reason why

I struggled with somehting similar. Eventually I dumped it because I had no time.

Some pointers though:
Site for JFIF: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000018.shtml

You dive into BASE64, but actually that is not the place to start. A base64 encoded jpeg will start with `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...`.

You don't have such a string. Your string representation starts with `ÿØÿà JFIF...`. That is exactly what you get for string representation when you would drag a jpeg file in a HEX editor. If you want to try it, and you do not have got a HEX Editor, then drag a jpeg file into notepad. You will see that it starts with `ÿØÿà JFIF`as well.

You might see some differences if you see the string representations of the image in the response of the service and in the notepad application. That is likely because of character encoding. Truth of the matter here is that the representation might be flawed because not each set of bytes can be represented by a character.

The key will be in finding out how to get grips on the actual byte array sent instead of the response which you can see, that is actually a byte array chewed on by SoapUI to be represented to the user of the SoapUI tool.

This thesis is supported by the following experiment:

1. Take the image as found on the web and save it
2. Save the Content from the SoapUI response body as a file
3. Open both in a hex editor
4. Compere the files on byte-code level

What you will find is that a substantial amount of characters (90,91, 80, 8D and 8F) are being replaced with 3F. 3F being the hexadecimal representation of a question mark. In other words: when there is no representation for a character set in which you are working, then all unknown characters are diverted to be question marks.

Further information can be found on http://www.i18nqa.com/iuc37-Texin-Critical%20values%20for%20i18n%20testing.pdf, slide 25.

81, 8D, 8F, 90, 9D are not yet assigned to a character according to this slide. And those are exactly the values that I found to be replaced with 3F in the hex in the file bytecode.

If you can get your hands on the message before it is transformed into text (RAW response), then there is hope. If the response is first saved to the SoapUI XML project file with the 'damage' already done, and then retrieved for further actions, then it is not possible to get the correct bytes because they are already replaced by the sequence for 3F.

You can do that with the OP's answer. I shortened it a bit because I only needed the write-to-disk part. If it fails I will see it in the report with the failing assertion.

Comment: When I know more, I'll share. This subject is valuable for me as well!

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I will continue as well checking. In any case I tried without the base64 stuff but did not get good results.